# css background color extend as far as text?

Tags: css

How would I set the background color of a text that doesn't expand to width of its parent `div`? I used `h1` `{background color:white;}` and wrapped `h1` around the text I want, but the white background just extends beyond text. It's almost like you're just highlighting the words.

Comment: why not change the color of the text and make the background-color:transparent? i'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Have you tried adding the background color on the div instead of the h1 element?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

h1 is a block element, so , it will use all the available area. so change this element to inline, for only use its width

```
h1 {
  display: inline;
  background-color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxNQR/

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that `h1` is a block-level element, and by default block level elements will expand to fill all the available width of the parent element.

The easiest way to solve this is to `float` the element:

```
h1 {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
}
```

You will then need to style the following paragraph, so that it doesn't flow round the heading element:

```
p {
    clear: left;
}
```

If you are comfortable not supporting IE7 and below, you can use the adjacent sibling selector to make this selection neater, so that only `p` elements directly after `h1` elements will be so styled:

```
h1 + p {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I find floats to be a major PITA, and disagree that floats present the _easiest_ solution. Why not just wrap the text in a `<span>`?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL OK, the "nicest semantic solution". Introducing a `span` solely for the sake of styling it is messy, IMO.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL because H1 might be the semantically correct element to use. IMO display:inline-block would be the nicest way to solve this - if only it were supported by IE7..

Comment: Thank but it looks like all I needed to do was add display:inline; for some reason h1 likes to break a new line after it and p clear:left; wouldn't stop the background color from extending.

Comment: @Ali You might want to look into what block level and inline elements are. It will probably help you fix this kind of issue in futuree.

Comment: h1 break a new line because it is a block element

Comment: yeah... I definitely do, I never understood the difference so I just use it and pray it does what I want. I will need to look into that. Thanks.